# Meaning of "second" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

> I saw your picture and I could tell from the second I saw it it's not Mr. X.

Can "second" here also stand for "the second picture"?

Comment: It has roughly the same meaning as "moment".  Not literally however many vibrations of the cesium atom, but a brief interval of time.

Comment: I dont understand your last sentence?

Comment: So do you think second has here the same meaning as moment or not?

Comment: The "second", the official unit of time, is defined as the time required for 9 billion vibrations of the cesium atom, or some such, to provide a precise, reproducible value for physicists and engineers.  The word "second", in the sense used by your example, is not nearly that precise, but merely means a "moment" or a brief interval of time.

Comment: Yes thats the definition of a time second, but what about the context?

Comment: Does it also mean a "time second" or does it mean "2." as the ordinal value?

Comment: **It means the same as "moment", which is a brief interval of time.**

Comment: It makes no sense really for "from the second I saw it" to mean anything but time.

Comment: @VictorBazarov So you also think that "second" here means "moment"?

Comment: I do, yes.  There is no doubt in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

The first of your possible sentences is the only one that's grammatical. The second one leaves us wondering "the second *what* I saw it?" "Second *time*" (meaning after seeing it once, seeing it again later) would work, but without that, the ordinal meaning doesn't fit. So that leaves only second as a unit of time. Conveniently, that's also a fairly idiomatic expression. "From the very {small unit of time; hour, minute, second, etc} I saw…" is quite common to express that something happened immediately, the *first* time introduced.

Answer (score 1):

> I could tell from the second I saw ***it*** it's not Mr. X.

The *it* boldfaced in the excerpt above makes it virtually impossible to understand *the second* here as a reference to a second picture.

If that *it* were not there you might parse *the second I saw* as *the second [which] I saw*. But that would require a 'gap' after *saw*, a missing object of *saw* which has been replaced by the relative pronoun. Since there is not a gap but an actual object, *it*, this parse is excluded.

Consequently we must understand the phrase as *from the second [when/at which] I saw it*: an adverbial, with *second* most readily understood in the temporal sense.

Comment: Amazing how a potential parsing of a clause/phrase can be ignored due to the syntactic invalidity of clauses later on in the sentence.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi What's even more amazing in this particular case is that the critical cue is the presence of a constituent which we know is required to be absent because the absence is inferred from a constituent which isn't even there! :-)

Comment: Thank you StoneyB for your answer, but I dont understand the comment of Senjougaha Hitagi. Is this critic to the answer of StoneyB? Or do all agree that we have to understand second in the sentence in a temporal meaning (like the moment i saw the one and only picture)?

Comment: @spacer234 Senjougaha Hitagi is, I think, agreeing with my analysis, and finding it remarkable that the ambiguity you perceived is resolved *after* the phrase in question - unusual in English.

Comment: You mean Senjougaha Hitagi thinks its remarkable here that there is an object (it) after the verb (saw) of the clause?

Comment: @spacer234 No, Senjougaha Hitagi thinks it remarkable that a constituent which occurs well *after* the word you ask about "retrospectively" determines its syntactic role. Usually in English we parse only left-to-right.

Comment: ah ok thank you, though I think it´s too hard to understand for me yet. All in all the answer you gave me first above is right, that "the it boldfaced in the excerpt above makes it virtually impossible to understand the second here as a reference to a second picture. [...] Consequently we must understand the phrase as from the second [when/at which] I saw it: an adverbial, with second most readily understood in the temporal sense."?

Comment: This pretty much answers the question. Had the O.P.'s sentence read: _I saw your picture and I could tell from the second that it's not Mr. X_, then that could indeed mean "from the second picture." However, with the entire phrase being "from the second I saw it," that **must** mean "from the moment I saw it," Moreover, the original wording doesn't even suggest a second picture.

Comment: Thank you J.R. But can this be a typing error with picture(s) and the orginal sentence would have to be: "I saw your pictures and I could tell from the second I saw it it's not Mr. X." Now the sentence suggests more than one picture. Can this change the meaning somehow or cant this be a typing error?

Comment: @spacer234 If you ***know*** the *it* to be an error, sure, that will be your reading: "The second picture I saw was clearly not Mr. X". But there is no reason in the sentence to suppose that the *it* is an error. The sentence reads entirely naturally with *second* = *moment*.

Comment: Ok thanks, but if the "it" is correct and "picture" is the typing error and that should mean "pictures", can that change the meaning? "I saw your **pictures** and I could tell from the second I saw it it's not Mr. X." Does that change the meaning too?

Comment: @spacer - It doesn't change the meaning, but it's now grammatically incorrect; it should read: _"I saw your **pictures** and I could tell from the second I saw **them** it's not Mr. X."_ If you want to use _second_ the other way, you could say: _"I saw your pictures and I could tell from **the second one I saw** that it's not Mr. X."_ The words and their order is very important here.

Comment: Ok thank you J.R. But can you also change "that" with "it" in your construction? So is that sentence correct? "I saw your pictures and I could tell from the second one I saw it it's not Mr. X." ?

Comment: @spacer234 No. The *that* which J.R. uses there is not the demonstrative pronoun but the subordinating conjunction.

Comment: OK thank you. Can you describe this (second I saw = moment)as an expression?

Comment: @spacer234 mmm -- I'm not sure what you mean by "expression". "Expression" is not a technical term in the sort of grammar I'm using, just a loose name for any more-or-less coherent string of words.

Comment: Well, i could ask the author of the sentence on my own what he means with "second I saw" and he answered that it is an expression. Then i could not contact him again. Therefore I wasnt sure if it all in all was just a typing error and he meant "second picture" or it is all in all fact he must have meant second = Moment like you and J.R. told me. So i thought it could help to identify the meaning if the author sees this construction as expression.

Comment: @spacer234 Ah. What he meant was "that's just the way we say it", which doesn't help much, does it! But I agree with Victor Bazarov: there is no doubt in my mind that second = moment here. 'cause, well, that's how we say it.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer :) since you all  tell it to me I believe you then that the meaning of second here is moment. I guess the whole original sentence is correct native (american) english? "I saw your picture and I could tell from the second I saw it it´s not Mr. X."